# Как повторно отправить форму?

Tags: javascript, html5

Пытаюсь сделать сообщения об ошибках в форме через `setCustomValidity`. Сообщение то я вывел, но после этого не отправляется форма. Просто по сабмиту повторно это же сообщение выводится (в хэндлер отправки не заходит). Без запроса на сервер (сообщение по ajax оттуда пришло).